# Updating an Event on a Google Calendar automatically sets EventAtendee to self

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I have traced a problem with the Google Calendar API to an automatism of either the API or server.
I want to create/update an Event in a particular calendar, which is the calendar for a real world room. So basically the calendar tracks the availability of a resource (a room).

When I create/update a google calendar event via Google's Java Calendar API, the event is automatically modified. The room's name is added as location, even though the location is not set, and even intentionally removed.
Then the weird stuff happens. A few seconds after insertion, some automatism finds the event, and tries to 'fix' it. The location string is removed, and instead the room is filled in as resource (attendance of type resource).
Even if I explicitly purged the EventAttendees list prior to commit, the creating calendar is entered as (resource-)attendee.

However since this particular calendar represents a resource, this seems both inherently wrong, and causes significant issues, because the room's name cannot be resolved in GoogleMaps, which in turn causes GoogleCalendar to apply the html strikethrough property to both the false Room and the Event itself.

In other words, whenever I enter an entry into the resources calendar, it will *look like it was cancelled*.

[image: How it looks in Google Calendar]

I have tried to add dummy information like `""`, `"-"`, or `"here"`, but the location string is always initially appended by the rooms name, and after a short moment, the resource is added.

Is there a way to prevent Google's automatisms from modifying my event, or can I insert such data, that this is not added?

Answer (score 0):

Aparrently, resource calendars that are set to 'auto accept' decline any event series in the past. You basically cannot set up a series of events that begins in the past, if the first element is your master event.
This might even be configurable.